# How could I capture wire shark traces on loop back interface?

Tags: capture, wireshark, loopback

How can I capture wireshark traces on the interface it is configured to capture the traces?

Comment: the statement seems bit confusing ! I just want to capture the wireshark trace on lo interface on fedora 9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you capture a trace on the `lo` interface with Wireshark is that you select the `lo` interface from the list of interfaces Wireshark offers.  (If it doesn't offer *any* interface, there's a permissions problem; see the Linux section of [the CapturePrivileges page on the Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges) for information on that.)

Comment: It offers the interface lo, but when started capturing I see nothing! that's actly my concern!

Comment: Then maybe there's no traffic being sent from the machine to itself - i.e., there's no traffic to see.  You're not going to see any traffic between your machine and *other* machines on the `lo` interface (and "other machines" includes virtual machines on the same host machine).

Comment: clearly there is an apache2 web server running on port 443.I was  accessing the web server thru firefox browser.Why would n't there be no traffic?

Comment: If the server and Firefox are running on the same machine, that should result in loopback interface traffic.  What happens if you just do "ping 127.0.0.1"?  Does any traffic show up?